# Read a text file to an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I know there are many questions about reading text files here but I have gone through all of them and I think I'm having some difficulty with syntax or SOMETHING because nothing that I've been trying has been working at all.

What I'm attempting to do is this:

```
1) read a text file inputed by user 
2) copy each individual line into an array, so each line is its own element in the array
```

I feel like I am very close but for some reason I can't figure out exactly how to get it to work!

Here is the relevant code I have right now:

I keep getting out of bounds exceptions in three locations which I've marked off.

Been working on this for quite a while not sure what to do next! Any ideas?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FindWords {

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{

    FindWords d = new Dictionary();
    ((Dictionary) d).dictionary();  //********* out of bounds here


}


/**
 * Validates and returns the dictionary inputed by the user.
 * 
 * @param
 * @return the location of the dictionary
 */
public static String getDict(){
    ///////////////////ASK FOR DICTIONARY////////////////////
    System.out.println("Please input your dictionary file");

    //initiate input scanner
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // input by user 
    String dictionary = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Sys.print: " + dictionary);


    //make sure there is a dictionary file
    if (dictionary.length() == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must enter a dictionary");
    }
    else return dictionary;
}

}
```

which calls on the class Dictionary:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Dictionary extends FindWords{

public void dictionary () throws IOException{

    String dict = getDict();

        String[] a = readFile(dict);  //********** out of bounds here

    int i = 0;
    while(a[i] != null){
        System.out.println(a[i]);
        i++;
    }

}





public static String[] readFile(String input) throws IOException{   


//read file
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input)));

System.out.println ();

int count = 0;
String[] array = new String[count];
try{
while (br.readLine() != null){
    array[count] = br.readLine(); //********out of bounds here
    count++;
}
br.close();
}
catch (IOException e){

}
return array;

}

}
```

Thank you for looking!

**Edit:**  Just fyi: I have my .txt file in the parent project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/my/file.txt"));
```

and then transform your list to an array if you want:

```
String[] myLines = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a zero-length array, hence the exception on the first iteration:

```
int count = 0;
String[] array = new String[count];
```

Since you probably don't know the expected size, work with a `List` instead:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String thisLine = null;
try{
    while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(thisLine);
    }
}
```

You can get the total size afterwards by:

```
list.size();
```

Or even better, go with morganos solution and use `Files.readAllLines()`.

Answer (score 1):

You start with an array size of zero...

```
int count = 0;
String[] array = new String[count];
```

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here :

- In Java, you can't expand arrays, i.e you have to know their length in advance when you instantiate them. Hence the ArrayOutOfBoundException. To make this easy, I suggest that you use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.
- In your `while` loop, you're making 2 calls to `br.readLine()`, so basically you're skipping one line out of 2.